# How do you replace text surrounded by a custom delimeter with <span> around it?

Tags: input-formats

### Overview

I want to have [action asterisks](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070405014855AAtFfur) in my posts. Basically, asterisks surrounding certain words. Examples: *gasp* or *giggle*

Simple enough. Now I could type that exactly into the editor but it needs to be styled via CSS. This of course calls for span tags.

However, I don't want to have to surround the text with span tags every time. Too tedious. I'll be using this often.

So, **how can I make it so Drupal takes some text and replaces it with span tags surrounding it?**

### In Other Words...

I want to be able to write simple custom tags around text like:

```
[=gasp=]
```

and then have Drupal automatically convert it to:

```
<span class="action">*gasp*</span>
```

### A Possible Solution?

I've been led to [the Custom Filter module](http://drupal.org/project/customfilter) and this seems closest to what I want. Now, it's already installed but in trying to add a 'rule', the module asks for the 'Pattern' to look for and the 'Replacement text'.

**The problem is I am terrible with regular expressions.**

Assuming this module is the right path, *can someone tell me what to put in these two forms so the filter works?* I have been holding this off for months because I was scared to ask for help.

If the Custom Filter module isn't what I need, what is the solution?

#### On a sidenote

I don't know what's a good custom tag to use. I came up with [=gasp=] but maybe you can recommend something better? Just as long as its short. I already use Markdown and don't want it to conflict with it.

Either way, **thanks for any help in advance**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) as the following in your custom module:

```
<?php

$string = '[=waves=] words <br/> words <br/> words [=jumps in air & rolls in ground=] <div>words</div>';
$pattern = '/\[=(.*?)\=]/i';
$replacement = '<span class="action">*$1*</span>';
print preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

which return:

```
<span class="action">*waves*</span> words <br/> words <br/> words <span class="action">*jumps in air & rolls in ground*</span> <div>words</div>
```

Comment: It works but when I enter "[=waves=] words <br/> words <br/> words [=jumps in air & rolls in ground=] <div>words</div>" the second instance isn't replaced.

Comment: the text can be made up of many characters, numbers, dashes, and spaces. Not just a single word. basically, a whole sentence. Sorry, don't think I made that clear.

Comment: so you can update patter to: `/\[=(.*?)\=]/i`, answer editted

Comment: Thank you so much my friend! You definitely deserve this check. Drupal users are so cool ^^